# Decoding the meaning of hcitool info extended features for a Bluetooth 4.0 device

Tags: bluetooth

I have an embedded Bluetooth 4.0 module (A Laird BT900 with uses a CSR 8811). I am trying to debug some issues that occur during discovery and connection with other devices. So I am trying to understand exactly what this device is communicating about its capabilities to others during an inquiry.

On my embedded module if I disable pairing, and then run hcitool info I see the following

```
$ sudo hcitool -i hci0 info 00:16:A4:0F:B9:98
Requesting information ...
    BD Address:  00:16:A4:0F:B9:98
    OUI Company: Ezurio Ltd (00-16-A4)
    Device Name: FOO BAR
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6) LMP Subversion: 0x2031
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
    Features page 0: 0xff 0x07 0x87 0x7e 0xd8 0x1f 0x5b 0x87
        <3-slot packets> <5-slot packets> <encryption> <slot offset> 
        <timing accuracy> <role switch> <hold mode> <sniff mode> 
        <park state> <RSSI> <channel quality> <CVSD> <paging scheme> 
        <power control> <broadcast encrypt> <EDR ACL 2 Mbps> 
        <EDR ACL 3 Mbps> <enhanced iscan> <interlaced iscan> 
        <interlaced pscan> <inquiry with RSSI> <AFH cap. slave> 
        <AFH class. slave> <LE support> <3-slot EDR ACL> 
        <5-slot EDR ACL> <sniff subrating> <pause encryption> 
        <AFH cap. master> <AFH class. master> <extended inquiry> 
        <LE and BR/EDR> <simple pairing> <encapsulated PDU> 
        <non-flush flag> <LSTO> <inquiry TX power> <EPC> 
        <extended features> 
    Features page 1: 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

If I set the device to pairable the output looks like this

```
$ sudo hcitool -i hci0 info 00:16:A4:0F:B9:98
Requesting information ...
    BD Address:  00:16:A4:0F:B9:98
    OUI Company: Ezurio Ltd (00-16-A4)
    Device Name: FOO BAR
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6) LMP Subversion: 0x2031
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
    Features page 0: 0xff 0x07 0x87 0x7e 0xd8 0x1f 0x5b 0x87
        <3-slot packets> <5-slot packets> <encryption> <slot offset> 
        <timing accuracy> <role switch> <hold mode> <sniff mode> 
        <park state> <RSSI> <channel quality> <CVSD> <paging scheme> 
        <power control> <broadcast encrypt> <EDR ACL 2 Mbps> 
        <EDR ACL 3 Mbps> <enhanced iscan> <interlaced iscan> 
        <interlaced pscan> <inquiry with RSSI> <AFH cap. slave> 
        <AFH class. slave> <LE support> <3-slot EDR ACL> 
        <5-slot EDR ACL> <sniff subrating> <pause encryption> 
        <AFH cap. master> <AFH class. master> <extended inquiry> 
        <LE and BR/EDR> <simple pairing> <encapsulated PDU> 
        <non-flush flag> <LSTO> <inquiry TX power> <EPC> 
        <extended features> 
    Features page 1: 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

The only difference between these two is what is in Features page 1. In one case the first byte is 0x02, and in the other it is 0x03.

So here is my question: What is the meaning of this byte? Where can I locate documentation about these extended features? Is this something that I can only get from the vendor, or is there some standard meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is: The extended features are documented in Table 3.3 in section section 3.3 "FEATURE MASK DEFINITION" of the Link Manager Protocol Specificiation which Volume 2 Part C the [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) v 5.2 (Pg 587). The HCI_Read_Remote_Extended_Features command is documented in sections 4.9 and 7.1.22.

I was able to find out the answer to this by performing a TCP dump, and analyzing the data in wireshark.

```
$ tcpdump -i bluetooth0 -w bt900_inquire_with_pairing_on.pcap &
[1] 26733
tcpdump: listening on bluetooth0, link-type BLUETOOTH_HCI_H4_WITH_PHDR (Bluetooth HCI UART transport layer plus pseudo-header), capture size 262144 bytes
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
    00:16:A4:0F:B9:98   FOO BAR
$ sudo hcitool -i hci0 info 00:16:A4:0F:B9:98
Requesting information ...
    BD Address:  00:16:A4:0F:B9:98
    OUI Company: Ezurio Ltd (00-16-A4)
    Device Name: FOO BAR
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6) LMP Subversion: 0x2031
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
    Features page 0: 0xff 0x07 0x87 0x7e 0xd8 0x1f 0x5b 0x87
        <3-slot packets> <5-slot packets> <encryption> <slot offset> 
        <timing accuracy> <role switch> <hold mode> <sniff mode> 
        <park state> <RSSI> <channel quality> <CVSD> <paging scheme> 
        <power control> <broadcast encrypt> <EDR ACL 2 Mbps> 
        <EDR ACL 3 Mbps> <enhanced iscan> <interlaced iscan> 
        <interlaced pscan> <inquiry with RSSI> <AFH cap. slave> 
        <AFH class. slave> <LE support> <3-slot EDR ACL> 
        <5-slot EDR ACL> <sniff subrating> <pause encryption> 
        <AFH cap. master> <AFH class. master> <extended inquiry> 
        <LE and BR/EDR> <simple pairing> <encapsulated PDU> 
        <non-flush flag> <LSTO> <inquiry TX power> <EPC> 
        <extended features> 
    Features page 1: 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
$ fg 1
tcpdump -i bluetooth0 -w bt900_inquire_with_pairing_on.pcap
^C44 packets captured
1021 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
$
```

From wireshark I scrolled through the packets and found a sequence:

- Command Status (Read Remote Supported Features)
- Read Remote Supported Features
- Command Status (Read Remote Extended Features)
- Read Remote Extended Features Complete

This last frame contained:

```
Bluetooth HCI Event - Read Remote Extended Features Complete
    Event Code: Read Remote Extended Features Complete (0x23)
    Parameter Total Length: 13
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Connection Handle: 0x000c
    Page Number: 1
    Max. Page Number: 1
    LMP Features
        .... ...0 = Secure Simple Pairing Host: False
        .... ..1. = LE Supported Host: True
        .... .0.. = Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable Host: False
        .... 0... = Secure Connections Host: False
        0000 .... = Reserved: 0x0
        Reserved: 00000000000000
```

This gave me a lot of search terms to help me find what I was looking for, and bit 1 is the "Secure Simple Pairing (Host Support) feature bit" per the LMP protocol spec.

Comment: I could have avoided the tcpdump if I started a capture in Wireshark on my Bluetooth0 interface (would have required running wireshark as a super user), and then running `sudo hcitool -i hci0 info 00:16:A4:0F:B9:98`.